# Prove that two integrals are equal

Tags: calculus

Draw the region whose area is $$\int_0^\infty \frac 1 {1+x^2} \,dx$$

Show that $\int_0^∞1/(1+x^2)\,dx = \int_0^1\sqrt{(1-y)/y}\, dy$

Do not evaluate or calculate any integral, use a pictoral argument or algebraic argument.

---

I drew the graph of the equation, and see what the question is basically asking.

Both expressions are the same: one expressed in terms of x, one in terms of y. One of the integrals uses vertical rectangles to sweep across the graph to cover the area (From 0 to infinity) and the other uses horizontal rectangles(from 0 to 1). I do not know how to prove that they are equal without evaluating them.

Comment: The integral represents the area of some region - can you see how there are some equal areas?

Comment: It sounds as if you've done most of it already. You just need to explain why both integrals find the same area.

Comment: It might be interesting to put it this way: find a geometric argument proving that the area enclosed by a witch of Agnesi and its asymptote equals the area of a circle.

Comment: By the way, use **\mathrm dx** to generate $\mathrm dx$ as oppposed to $dx$ if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

LHS is $\frac \pi2$ because it is half the well-known integral which becomes  $[\arctan x]_{-\infty}^{\infty } $, that is, it's half the area under $\frac1{1+x^2}$...

RHS is also $\frac\pi2$, as it computes the area of half the unit circle, as seen by a change of variables ...

In a word, both are half the area of the unit circle...